Scaling DiracComb does not work properly in NDSolve
The code below is for a simple first order ADC converter and works properly. DiracComb is to sample the signal y[t].
NDSolveValue[{y'[t] + z[t] == Sin[t], 
              z'[t] == y[t] DiracComb[t] - y[t - 1] DiracComb[t], 
              y[t /; t <= 0] == 0, z[t /; t <= 0] == 0}, {y, z}, {t, 0, 10}]

But when I try to increase the sampling rate, there will be a lot of warnings no matter what options I tried (increase accuracy/maxsteps, different method)
NDSolveValue[{y'[t] + z[t] == Sin[t], 
              z'[t] == y[t] DiracComb[10 t] - y[t - 1/10] DiracComb[10 t], 
              y[t /; t <= 0] == 0, z[t /; t <= 0] == 0}, {y, z}, {t, 0, 10}]


Divide::infy
Infinity::indet
NDSolveValue::nlnum

A finding here is that with a lower sampling rate e.g. DiracComb[8 t] and y[t - 1/8] all warnings disappear.
I also tried Sum[DiracDelta[10 t - i], {i, -1, 10}] to replace DiracComb but got the same warnings.

Please avoid asking distinctly different questions in one post.

DSolveValue[{y'[t] + z[t] == Sin[t],    z'[t] ==     y[t]*Sum[Dirac[t - n], {n, -20, 20}] -      y[t - 1]   Sum[Dirac[t - n], {n, -20, 20}], y[t /; t <= 0] == 0,    z[t /; t <= 0] == 0}, {y, z}, {t, 0, 10}] instantly returns the input in 14.0 on Windows 10.

The product y[t] DiracComb[10 t] is defined only for smooth y[t], but in all  given  answers it is not so. I think your problem is incorrectly posed.

@user64494  Where does the claim "
The product y[t] DiracComb[10 t] is defined only for smooth y[t]" come from?  QP tries to model a ADC converter.

@UlrichNemann:  For example, see "Multiplication of distributions by smooth functions" in Wiki  and Encyclopedia of Mathematics and  Walter Rudin, Functional analysis, McGraw-Hill, NY, St. Louis,..., 1973,Chap.6.

@Ulrich Neumann Yes, it is indeed a simple ADC converter(with DAC feedback). I deleted the introduction part since I felt it would confuse others. We can read from the edit history anyway. Based on the ADC knowledge. increasing sampling rate will definitely make output closer to the input signal. That's why I dont feel the results of other answers are correct.

If we treat y[t] as a distribution, then the supports of y[t] and DiracComb[t] must not intersect in order to define its product, but this is not so in all three answers.

I don't have much experience with delay differential equation, but the usual workaround approximating DiracDelta with a continuous function seems to work in this case:
dirac[r_, a_] = Sqrt[a/Pi] Exp[-a r^2];
diraccomb[r_, a_] = dirac[Mod[r, 1, -1/2], a];

tend = 10; k = 10; scale = 10^4;

dc = diraccomb[#, scale] &(*DiracComb*); 

tst = 
 NDSolveValue[{y'[t] + z[t] == Sin[t], z'[t] == y[t] dc[k t] - y[t - 1/k] dc[k t], 
   y[t /; t <= 0] == 0, z[t /; t <= 0] == 0}, {y, z}, {t, 0, tend}, 
  MaxStepSize -> 10^-3, MaxSteps -> Infinity];

ListLinePlot@tst[[2]]


I've used the undocumented feature of ListLinePlot as mentioned here to plot InterpolatingFunction[…] directly.
If you want to test larger k, you may need to set a smaller MaxStepSize to avoid the NDSolveValue::ndssc warning.

The result is close to DiracComb[8 t]. One thing confuses me is that the preferred output shall look like a full sale sine wave as the input Sin[t]. Sampling is actually a relative thing. We can use Sin[t/10] to confirm the output swing.

@metroidman I'm not sure if I've understood your comment. Do you mean the z should be a scaled zigzag sine wave as k->Infinity? If so, the current k is still too small. Try e.g. k = 30 with MaxStepSize -> 10^-3/6.

No. I simply mean we can keep the DiracDelta[t] while changing Sin[x] to Sin[x/10]. Such scaling is equivalent to directly changing DiracDelta[t] to DiracDelta[10t].@xzczd

@metroidman Did you change the Sin term only? If so, you've forgotten something: DSolveChangeVariables[Inactive[DSolve][y'[x] == y[x], y, x], y, ξ, x == 10 ξ]

The product y[t] DiracComb[10 t] is defined only for smooth y[t], but in your answer it is not so: y[t is not even continuous.

To avoid troubling MMA with complicated functions(DiracComb and DDE), we use WhenEvent instead.
ListLinePlot@
NDSolveValue[{y'[t] + a[t] == Sin[t], y[0] == 0, a[0] == 0, 
WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1/10] == 0, a[t] -> y[t]]}, {y, a}, {t, 0, 10},DiscreteVariables -> a]



The product y[t] DiracComb[10 t] is defined only for smooth y[t], but in your answer it is not so: y[t] is not even continuous.

addendum to   @xzczd's answer
k=.
sol[k_] := NDSolveValue[{y'[t] + z[t] == Sin[t], 
z'[t] == y[t] dc[k t] - y[t - 1/k] dc[k t], y[t /; t <= 0] == 0, 
z[t /; t <= 0] == 0}, {y, z}, {t, 0, tend},MaxStepSize -> 1/1000 ];

case k=1 ( "Staircase function" ) :
Plot[Evaluate[Through[sol[1][t]]], {t, 0, tend}]


case k=10 ( "smooth" ) :
Plot[Evaluate[Through[sol[10][t]]], {t, 0, tend}]



The product y[t] DiracComb[10 t] is defined only for smooth y[t], but in your answer it is not so: y[t] is not even continuous.
